# Automatic Screen Popup

Tags: popup, window, screen, ads

How to get HTML & CSS welcome popup on screen automatically without clicking on any buttons/text? I want something like this: [Screen window popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rRX1g.png)

Comment: You should show what you have tried, please edit your Q and post your code. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably want to use [Bootstrap's modal class](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals) [(method section link)](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-methods) and then wrap the show.bs.modal call in a [JQuery $(document).ready() statement.](https://api.jquery.com/ready/) What you're asking for isn't possible with pure HTML/CSS as far as I know.

[A simple example.](http://jsfiddle.net/xdL5egre/1/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myModal').modal();
});
```

Comment: I found my answer after a long, long time...This is it! :) http://stefanpage.ml/questions/test-1.html

Comment: Really thanks, you helped me alot! But i already founded my answer on web. I will save this. Thank you again! :)